# Split a dataframe's columns containing dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I realized the first version I published was really unclear and not compliant to the website rules, I am sorry for this. I deleted the previous one and made it clearer.

This is my first post and I did research about my problem but I couldn't find a solution.

Actually, I have a DataFrame  like this (The column SecurityInfo contains dictionaries that I will detail below)

```
  Rent_ID     UserId  Car_Id  Rent_Date     SecurityInfo
    0           1        2    2018/05/09     dict_1
    1           2        4    2018/05/10     dict_2
    2           3        6    2018/05/11     dict_3
```

Below you can see how the dictionaries look like. One dictionary per cell.

```
{
    "car_consumption": 99,
    "car_route_option": "None",
    "safetyEvents": [{
                  "latitude": 99.140763200350641,
                  "longitude": -9.6871865486956645,
                  "time": 1121,
                  "type": 3
             }, {
                  "latitude": 99.115982330953294,
                  "longitude": -9.5833240979286927,
                  "time": 1710,
                  "type": 1
             }, {
                  "latitude": 99.115982330953294,
                  "longitude": -9.5833240979286927,
                  "time": 1710,
                  "type": 2
    },
    "pollutant": {
        "trip": 8.0129999999999999,
        "nox": 44.960000000000001,
        "co": 28.300000000000001,
        "global": 8.7065000000000001
    },
    "ecoDriving": {
        "scoreAccel": 2.5,
        "score": 9.4000000000000004,
        "scoreMain": 3.1000000000000001
    }
}
```

As you can see the SafetyEvent key is a nested key, that also contains a list of dictionary

I would like to get that kind of output

```
      Rent_ID     UserId  Car_Id  Rent_Date   Car_Consumption  car_route_option         SafetyEvent       trip   nox    co     global    scoreAccel    score    scoreMain
        0           1        2    2018/05/09      99                None           list1_of_SafetyEvent   
        1           2        4    2018/05/10      95                Good           list2_of_SafetyEvent 
        2           3        6    2018/05/11      96                 Bad           list3_of_SafetyEvent
```

I tried to use the function below, but it worked only when I pass a dataframe containing only one dictionary, it doesnt accept a dataframe column as parameter

```
def unpack(df, column, fillna=None):


    ret = None  # Intitlisation retour
    if fillna is None:   # Si 
        ret = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame((d for idx, d in df[column].iteritems()))], axis=1)
        del ret[column]
    else:
        ret = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame((d for idx, d in df[column].iteritems())).fillna(fillna)], axis=1)
        del ret[column]
    return ret
```

I also tried this but it didnt work,

```
df_SafetyEvent = pd.DataFrame(df['SecurityInfo'].values.tolist(), index=df.index)
```

it seems like my dictionaries are not detected as dictionaries, but i checked the type, they actually are.

Thank you for whom may help, if my post is not compliant let me know, I will correct it.

Comment: How working my solution?

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much, I am testing it, I let you know. in some minutes.